# Count(*) Keep(Dense_rank last order by time stamp)

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

```sql
Select source as source,
       Count(*) keep(Dense_Rank last order by timestamp) as numbers
From   My_table
Group by 
       Source
```

I have table in Oracle database where everyday new data loads happens and I want to get data base on last load. I want to avoid use of aggregate function so I tried using `keep dense_rank` function it's throwing error...

Comment: "it's throwing error..." What error? Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for some sample data that is representative of the problem; it complete text of the error message for your query; a detailed (English, not code) description of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. If you cannot tell use what is wrong and what you are trying to achieve then how are we supposed to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact you did not provide us with test data and desired output, I'm sure I can follow you needs.

If you're on version 12 or newer, you may use "fetch ... with ties" feature.

```
select some_date
  from some_dates
 order by some_date desc       -- sorts newest records to the top of result
 fetch first 1 row with ties;  -- "with ties" shows not the first line only but also the lines that have same value
```

Under the hood, this feature uses RANK or DENSE_RANK to find lines to show but still it might be what you're looking for

[Here's an example](https://dbfiddle.uk/YCQQ6mjG)